# symfony2 - FOSUserBundle - send emails from address based on current locale

Tags: php, symfony, email, translation, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle and jmsI18nRouting. Emails send from fos (register, reset password etc.) are translatable. But they all are being send from one address.

When on english version, user should get emails from different email address then user using french version. Is there a possibility to manage that in fos config?

Answer (score 0):

In the FOSUserBundle config itself it isn't possible as far as I know.

My solution would be to overwrite the mailer service used by the bundle.
Then you can modify the public functions inside it and adjust it to your users desire.

The Mailer class is located in `FOS\UserBundle\Mailer` and the service id is `fos_user.mailer.default`